# GridPane unintended row resize

Tags: javafx, javafx-8, javafx-2

I've created GridPane containing panels. Every panel is Pane. Click on every panel should add a point (Circle) to the panel. A problem emerges when adding the point to the bottom border of the panel which resizes the panel. I can't see any particular reason for it to happen while the size of the panel (Pane) is not affected in any way. I seek for an explanation and possible fix.
For the demo reasons only the top panel is point addable.

```java
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.HPos;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.VPos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.ColumnConstraints;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.layout.Priority;
import javafx.scene.layout.Region;
import javafx.scene.layout.RowConstraints;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class GridPaneApp extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        int columns = 1;
        int rows = 2;

        GridPane gridPane = new GridPane();
        gridPane.setHgap(4);
        gridPane.setVgap(4);
        gridPane.setPadding(new Insets(4));

        for (int i = 0; i < columns; i++) {
            gridPane.getColumnConstraints().add(new ColumnConstraints(Region.USE_COMPUTED_SIZE, Region.USE_COMPUTED_SIZE, Region.USE_COMPUTED_SIZE, Priority.ALWAYS, HPos.CENTER, true));
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
            gridPane.getRowConstraints().add(new RowConstraints(Region.USE_COMPUTED_SIZE, Region.USE_COMPUTED_SIZE, Region.USE_COMPUTED_SIZE, Priority.ALWAYS, VPos.CENTER, true));
        }

        for (int columnIndex = 0; columnIndex < columns; columnIndex++) {
            for (int rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < rows; rowIndex++) {
                Pane pane = new Pane();
                pane.setStyle("-fx-background-color: purple, white; -fx-background-insets: 0, 1;");
                gridPane.getChildren().add(pane);
                GridPane.setConstraints(pane, columnIndex, rowIndex, 1, 1, HPos.CENTER, VPos.CENTER, Priority.ALWAYS, Priority.ALWAYS);
                if (rowIndex == 0) {
                    pane.setOnMousePressed(event -> {
                        double x = event.getX();
                        double y = event.getY();
                        System.out.println("x=" + x + ", y=" + y);
                        Circle circle = new Circle(8, Color.PURPLE);
                        circle.setLayoutX(x);
                        circle.setLayoutY(y);
                        pane.getChildren().add(circle);
                    });
                }
            }
        }

        Scene scene = new Scene(gridPane, 800, 600);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: don't know how exactly this is happening - but layout problems usually need to be solved in the parent (that is the gridPane). The pane doesn't do much except reporting its own pref as the "bounding box" around its children (at their location, having pref). So if you add a circle near the lower edge of the pane, the bounding box is increased by the bounds of that circle. And if there's still enough space (the other rows don't reclaim it), the increased child will get all available. Didn't dig, though, on the run right now :)

Comment: Bounding box of the Pane is not increased by the bounding box of the Circle. Simple SceneBuilder test will show that you can put Circle as a child of the Pane but out of its area. Pane bounding box won't be affected.

Comment: the pane's prefHeight is definitely increased when adding a circle somewhere in the below another - whatever scenebuilder tells you, just add a sysout to your code ;)